# null value in entry: otherfileoutputs=null

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting following error in gradle build.

`null value in entry: otherfileoutputs=null`

clean build didn't work :/
How can I fix this?

Note: my explorer.exe is crashing every now and then.

Comment: Well explorer.exe shows that you have problem with your computer, try toremove .gradle directory and update gradle to latest version

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try removing the .gradle folder i the project dirrectory and rebuilding the project again. This worked for me

Comment: yah that help me a lots Thanks

Comment: Can confirm, this worked.  I believe OneDrive messed up my project because I switch between multiple PC's quite often.  Clearing the .gradle folder and deleting any copied files from OneDrive synchronization seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

See if you are passing values to the `otherfileoutputs` variable

Maybe you're trying to do something with that variable but you dont have anithing inside her

Comment: I don't have this variable in any gradle file

Answer (score 0):

I stuck in the problem like this. What I done is **Delete the .Gradle Folder From the Project File**.

Then Built and Clean the Project. My Problem is resolved when I do the below method.

Delete .Gradle Folder -> Clean-> Built the project